# Drop rows based on date condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, rows

I have a Pandas DataFrame called `new` in which the `YearMonth` column has date in the format of YYYY-MM. I want to drop the rows based on the condition: if the date is beyond "2020-05". I tried using this:

```
new = new.drop(new[new.YearMonth>'2020-05'].index)
```

but its not working displaying a syntax error of "invalid token".

Here is a sample DataFrame:

```py
>>> new = pd.DataFrame({
    'YearMonth': ['2014-09', '2014-10', '2020-09', '2021-09']
})
>>> print(new)
    YearMonth
0   2014-09
1   2014-10
2   2020-09
3   2021-09
```

The expected DataFrame after the drop should be:

```
    YearMonth
0   2014-09
1   2014-10
```

Comment: Can you post a sample dataframe ?

Comment: sorry but i am new to this platform. How to post it?

Comment: try `pandas.to_datetime(new.YearMonth) > datetime(2020,05)` ... note that it will probably exlude any dates after the first of the month (as opposed to the end of the month)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: I have edited your question with what I understood. Review it and approve, if it is what you expect

Answer (score 1):

**Just convert to datetime, then format it to month and subset it.**

```
from datetime import datetime as dt

new['YearMonth']=pd.to_datetime(new['YearMonth']).dt.to_period('M')
new=new[~(new['YearMonth']>'2020-05')]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with change `>` to `<=` so comparing by month periods working nice:

```
new = pd.DataFrame({
    'YearMonth': pd.to_datetime(['2014-09', '2014-10', '2020-09', '2021-09']).to_period('m')
})
print (new)
  YearMonth
0   2014-09
1   2014-10
2   2020-09
3   2021-09

df = new[new.YearMonth <= pd.Period('2020-05', freq='m')]
print (df)
  YearMonth
0   2014-09
1   2014-10
```

In newest versions of pandas also working with compare by strings:

```
df = new[new.YearMonth <= '2020-05']
```

Comment: there's an error while converting. <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.period.Period'> is not convertible to datetime

Comment: @SpandanRout - Can you test now?

Comment: apparently the YYYY-MM is not in datetime format rather its an object. and while converting it shows an error message as earlier, And while testing the recent code it showed this error: TypeError: Cannot compare type 'Period' with type 'str'

Comment: @SpandanRout - Can you test now?